# bootstrap selectjs is not working for dynamically appended value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why `bootstrap selectjs` is not working for dynamically appended value.

whenever i append new option from `javascript` it is not reflected to the live search.

**below is code snippet**

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#demo').append('<option>India</option>');
  console.log('appended');
},1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select id="demo" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" >
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Alaska </option>
    <option>Arizona </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `refresh` method to refresh the picker with your new appended option.

```
$('#demo').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Reference:

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is appending the new option the list need to be [refreshed](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) after appending new element.Also note there is a `display:none` set to default HTML select tag

[image: DOM view aftre appending new option]

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#demo').append('<option>India</option>').selectpicker('refresh');
  console.log('appended');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<select id="demo" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Alaska </option>
    <option>Arizona </option>
</select>
```